# Could not load file or assembly as exe file

Tags: c#, exe, release

I have a C# program that uses the ZipFile class.
I converted the program to an exe file (using the release configuration).
I tried to run the exe file on a computer that doesn't have visual studio installed, and I got the exception: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'`.

Why is it happening? The exe file should run on any windows computer.

Comment: Is the right .Net Framework / .Net Core runtime installed on the target machine? .Net (c# and vb.net) programs do not compile to a native OS executable - they need the runtime installed to execute it.

Comment: When you copied the executable to the pc without visual studio - did you copy all of the contents of the folder the exe file was created in - including all of the dlls. If you created a shortcut to the exe - did you make sure the working directory was also set to theexe folder?